# How to use index integer in IF statement when checking if index integer exists in logic downstream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Apologies if the title is confusing.

I have a dataframe where I want to check if 2 integers exist in the index. If either of those numbers exists, I want to use only those two index values to compare another column `col1` to see if that column value is null for either of those two integer values.

If the column is null return the integer of the index to be used later on.

I am stuck on writing the next part after the IF statement.

If either of those clauses are TRUE, how do I use the integer that fulfills that criteria for logic further on?

```
if 19 in session_final.index or 49 in session_final.index:
       **Not sure what to do to retrieve the integer that fulfilled this criteria**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use:

```
df[df.index.isin([19, 49]) & df['col1'].notna()]
```

If need return integer of index:

```
df.index[df.index.isin([19, 49]) & df['col1'].notna()]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'col1':[np.nan,3,5,7,1,0],
}, index=[19,49,4,5,6,7])
print (df)
    col1
19   NaN
49   3.0
4    5.0
5    7.0
6    1.0
7    0.0

a = df.index[df.index.isin([19, 49]) & df['col1'].notna()]
print (a)
Int64Index([49], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly

```
df[~df[df.index.isin((19, 49))]['col1'].isnull()]
```

will give you a dataframe that have index either in (19, 49) and `col1` is not null.

Then you can check that the dataframe is emtpy or not, then check value.

Comment: I like the 1 liner!

Comment: @RustyShackleford - Not understand question, so my answer was edited.

Comment: @hunzter sorry buddy jezrael answer also helps me pick blank and nan